# Django restrict foreign key options

Tags: django, django-models

So I have three models:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField('ID', default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    start_time = models.TimeField('Start Time', default=None)
    end_time = models.TimeField('End Time', default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(str(self.start_time), str(self.end_time))


class Slot(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField('ID', default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    timings = models.ForeignKey('Session', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='slot_timings')
    available_counsellors = models.ManyToManyField(User, limit_choices_to={'role': 'COUNSELLOR'}, related_name='available_counsellors')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.timings)


class ChatSession(models.Model):

    def get_access_code():
        while True:
            access_code = get_random_string(length=6, allowed_chars=('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'))
            if not ChatSession.objects.filter(access_code=access_code).exists():
                return access_code

    id = models.UUIDField('ID', default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={'role': 'CLIENT'}, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='client_user')
    counsellor = models.ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={'role': 'COUNSELLOR'}, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='counsellor_user')
    access_code = models.CharField('Access Code', default=get_access_code, max_length=6)
    topic = models.CharField('Topic', default=None, blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    slot = models.ForeignKey(Slot, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.topic)
```

In the chat session model, I want to limit the options for counsellor field to the available_counsellors list in slot model.
How can I do this??

I want the same to reflect in my admin view also.

Comment: Normally you would set `queryset` on the relevant form field to something like `chat_session.slot.available_counsellors`. But when creating a new `ChatSession` there will be no `slot` value. What should the `counsellor` options be in this situation?

Comment: Initially both can be null I guess

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `queryset` on the `counsellor` form field.

Assuming you are using a ModelForm, you can do this in your view:

```py
chat_session = ChatSession.objects.get(pk=1)
form = ChatSessionForm(instance=chat_session)
form.fields["counsellor"].queryset = chat_session.slot.available_counsellors
```

You can alternatively do it in your ModelForm:

```py
class ChatSessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super (ChatSessionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and self.instance.slot:
            options = self.instance.slot.available_counsellors
        else
            options = User.objects.none()
        self.fields['counsellor'].queryset = options
```

For Django admin, something like this should work:

```py
class ChatSessionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['obj'].slot:
            options = kwargs['obj'].slot.available_counsellors
        else:
            options = User.objects.none()
        context['adminform'].form.fields['counsellor'].queryset = options
        return super(ChatSessionAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, args, kwargs)
```